# zf2 Uncaught Runtime exception 'No RouteMatch instance provided' with route i18n

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, lang

I have an issue since i include lang in route params for Zf2. My valid routes are fine and it's working. But when i give a wrong route, this exception comes and it's not caught by zf2 :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No RouteMatch instance provided'[path]\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Url.php on line 64
```

This is a sample of code wich i suspect to be invalid in case of wrong route :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="<?= $this->url($this->route, array('lang' => 'fr'));?>">
                                <span class="flag fr"></span> Français
                            </a></li>
                            <li><a href="<?=$this->url($this->route, array('lang' => 'en'));?>">
                                <span class="flag gb"></span> English
                            </a></li>
                        </ul>
```

It makes sense, this->route is incorrect when a wrong path is provided, what i need to change for fix that please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [line 62 of  the `Zend\View\Helper\Url` helper](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/Url.php#L62), it's clear that the exception will only be raised if you pass `NULL` in as the `$name` argument.

```
// ...Zend\View\Helper\Url.php
if ($name === null) {
    if ($this->routeMatch === null) {
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException('No RouteMatch instance provided');
    }
```

Therefore you need to ensure that the `$this->route` view variable is correctly set *before* you use it.

Comment: Yeah i understand that, and i tried to fix it, but i have to modify all my routes in all views with getHelperPluginManager for checking routeMatch and params, i thought there is a better way to do this.... is it ?

Comment: @Hooli Why are you passing the route name in as a variable? Why not hard code it?

Comment: Because if i'm in a route like www.monsite.com/en/album and i switch to fr i wanna keep album not redirected to home... need variable here.

Answer (score 1):

In your *AnyModule*\Module.php write lines below

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application         = $e->getApplication();
    $eventManager        = $application->getEventManager();

    /**
     * Zf2 View Url helper bug fix
     * The problem is Url helper always requires RouteMatch
     * if you used null in route name or set reuse matches to true
     * even in 404 error but 404 itself means that there is not any route match ;)
     */
    $eventManager->attach(
        \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, 
        function ($e) {
            $application    = $e->getApplication();
            $serviceLocator = $application->getServiceManager();
            $match          = $application->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();

            if (null === $match) {
                $params     = [
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'not-found',
                    // Here you can add common params for your application routes
                ];
                $routeMatch = new \Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch($params);

                $routeMatch->setMatchedRouteName('home');
                $application->getMvcEvent()->setRouteMatch(
                    $routeMatch
                );
            }
        }
    );
}
```